# Joining two dataframes in Pandas remove value from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes tran and user 
[image]

I need to get output dataframe as tran dataframe have a UserID not in users.

Expected Output

[image]

Comment: Not a `numpy` or `machine-learning` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Please avoid posting images. Hard to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right:

```
tran[~tran.UserID.isin(users.UserID)]
```

will give you tran df with only the user ids that are not user df

Comment: Thanks @alextesy

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can use `sqldf`:

```
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
pysqldf("SELECT tran.*  
         FROM tran 
         WHERE‌ tran.UserId NOT IN‌ (SELECT‌ UserId FROM users)") \
.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
tran_filt = tran[~(tran['UserId'].isin(users['UserId'].tolist()))]
```